# Adding a polygon layer from data

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcgis-online

I'm working on a project for my GIS class, I'm covering the redistricting of Tennessee in 2021 compared to the census data from 2020. I want show the distribution of race and age as separate layers. I know how to make the layers interactable, but I'm struggling on how to add the data for the layers. I have found the census data I need, but I don't know how to assign that value to each county

I've tried using the geography feature in excel but that won't work, whenever I upload a spreadsheet it won't process that I want that value added to that county, it will just say NULL. I have no idea where to really start beyond that. I know I can add data from excel, and that single points often use coordinates, but I need to assign the value to a whole county